# unable to run " .jar" file on windows 7

Tags: windows, jnlp, java-web-start

while running .jar file getting following error

```
MissingFieldException[ The following required field is missing from the launch file: ]
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: i should run my .jar file on different windows systems.so when i double click on jar file i should be able to run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JNLP is probably invalid.  Be sure to check it using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Comment: got a temporary solution by converting .jar file to .exe file  here is the link that help u    ::::::::::http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/02/convert-jar-to-exe-executable-jar-file-to-exe-converting.html

Comment: why would you go with exe if you can run on java web start